# Can't create Dexterity content type programatically in Plone 4.3.1

Tags: plone, zope, dexterity

I created a new content type using the Dexterity manager in Site Setup. I'm able to successfully add content through the Plone user interface, but I've come to a point where I need to create the same object with a python script.

My first attempt was with invokeFactory:

```
context.invokeFactory("mycontenttype", id="test", Title="Test")
```

This same code works for "Folder" objects, but fails with my Dexterity type:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 60, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Products.PloneHotfix20130618.spamProtect, line 35, in _patched_bindAndExec
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 7, in test
   - <PythonScript at /three-year-plan/test>
   - Line 7
TypeError: invokeFactory() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

After doing some more searching, I found several places referring to the following function:

```
from plone.dexterity.utils import createContentInContainer
```

Any attempt to import from plone.dexterity.utils in my python scripts ends up with a permissions error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 60, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  zModule ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Products.PloneHotfix20130618.spamProtect, line 35, in _patched_bindAndExec
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 1, in test
    - <PythonScript at /my-site/test>
    - Line 1
  Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 305, in guarded_import
  Unauthorized: import of 'plone.dexterity.utils' is unauthorized
```

Any help in resolving the errors above or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated. Version details are posted below for reference.

**Version Overview**

```
Plone 4.3.1 (4306)
CMF 2.2.7
Zope 2.13.19
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug 1 2012, 05:14:39) [GCC 4.6.3]
PIL 1.7.8 (Pillow)
Dexterity Content Types 2.0.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use "invokeFactory" for this purpose. You call it on the container and pass it the type name as a string.

I'm not sure where your attempt to use the invokeFactory method went awry, but it does work. See http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/reference/manipulating-content-objects.html?highlight=invokefactory#adding-an-object-to-a-container for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is right: you have to use createContentInContainer.
But you cannot use it in a Python script because only the so called restricted Python is allowed [1]. Put it in a view [2].

As a reference have a look to:

1. http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/helloworld/extend/view.html
2. http://plone.org/documentation/faq/restricted-python-scripts

Comment: We should give some thought to whether or not the Dexterity convenience functions should be marked safe for scripting. File a feature request ticket at dev.plone.org. If you'd like to try doing that yourself, https://github.com/collective/collective.localfunctions may help.